# Combing AND and OR within SQLite raw query within android

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm trying to display items from a database into a listview for all dates within a week after a user selects the first day of the week. To my understanding this should have worked but keeps crashing the app. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code for my cursor......

```
mCursor = mDb.query("tracker", null, 
                "(day_id=? OR day_id=? OR day_id=? OR day_id=? OR day_id=? OR day_id=? OR day_id=?) AND year_id=? AND month_id=? ", new String[] { 
                 String.valueOf(day1), String.valueOf(day1+1), String.valueOf(day1+2), String.valueOf(day1+3),
                String.valueOf(day1+4), String.valueOf(day1+5), String.valueOf(day1+6), String.valueOf(year1), 
                String.valueOf(month1)}, 
                null, null,  "_id ASC");
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.......

Comment: Could you possibly put a stack trace or any sort of error message that you got?

Comment: Yipes! What a query! Consider doing this query: `WHERE day_id BETWEEN ? AND ? AND month_id = ? AND year_id = ?`.

Comment: Also, could you give the structure of the SQL table you are working with?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your really quick responses. My error was coming from another null pointer within my activity which is fixed now when I checked my error messages. My sql query was not giving me the correct results until I changed it to the one Chris suggested which worked a treat. As I'm a complete newbie I didn't realise you could query in such a manner. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else looking for the answer this was suggested by Chris Jester-Young above, thanks again

```
mCursor = mDb.query("tracker", null, 
    " day_id BETWEEN ? AND ? AND year_id=? AND month_id=? ", new String[] { 
        String.valueOf(day1), String.valueOf(day2), String.valueOf(year1), 
        String.valueOf(month1)
    }, 
    null, null,  "_id ASC");
```